# Error in "as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE): cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame" when using the gamlss function (or lme())

Tags: r, nlme, beta-distribution, gamlss

I am trying to fit a **one-inflated Beta regression mixed model** using the `gamlss` package using the following code:

```
# Minimal reproducible example:
efficiency <- rbeta(n = 85, shape1 = 2, shape2 = 2, ncp = 2) # My actual variable contains several "ones", but it does not matter here
distance <- rpois(n = 85, lambda = 4)
manager_id <- c(rep(1, 10), rep(2, 2), 3:75)
manager_id <- as.factor(manager_id)
eff <- data.frame(efficiency, distance, manager_id)

mod1 <- gamlss::gamlss(efficiency~distance + gamlss::re(random = ~1|manager_id, method = "ML"),
                      data = eff, family = gamlss.dist::BEOI())
```

Yet I get the following error:

```
Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘"function"’ to a data.frame
```

I believe the error comes from the `nlme::lme()` function that is called by `gamlss::re()` to fit the random effect because it works fine when I do not include this part of the code. I could perhaps use `gamlss::random()` instead of `gamlss::re()` to fit the random effect but the help page of these functions states that `re()` should be used when the *normality assumption* of the response variable cannot be satisfied.
Could someone please help me figure out how to solve this problem?

Comment: FYI, stop using `data.frame(cbind(..))`, just use `data.frame`; the column names and data are *mostly* the same, but when using your current method, the factors are converted back to strings (see `str(eff)`, showing `num` in my console). I don't know if that would break the random effects, but it is the difference in *appearance* between a categorical and continuous variable `manager_id`. (I don't have `gamlss` installed, so cannot further test.) Good luck!

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your comment, I will change the code accordingly. However, in my actual dataset, `manager_id` truly is a `factor` and so the error is triggered by something else.

Comment: If you use `re()` without `gamlss::` before it seems to be ok, actually I don't know why but I can't find the re() source code and maybe we can't call it from gamlss

Comment: @BastienDucreux you are right, thank you! This is strange indeed but now the code works (yet the model does not seem to fit my data well, but that's another problem).